# How to install JessyInk in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

I tried to install jessyink in ubuntu doing the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jessyink-team/ppa
```

then update

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jessyink-team/ppa
```

finally:

```
sudo apt-get install jessyink
```

but the following error is showed:

> E: Unable to locate package jessyink

I'm in lubuntu 16

Comment: That ppa only has packages for older releases, such as Ubuntu 10.04. The packages are from December 2009, so the project seems abandoned.

Comment: You could clone from this repository https://github.com/oriolpont/jessyink-hackish for example.

Comment: @edwinksl there is no way to install via apt?

Comment: @DamianLattenero Nope, no way for Ubuntu 16.04 unless you want to make your own PPA.